# Root Device UUID Error while installing Mountain Lion on VirtualBox 4.3

Tags: macos, memory, virtualization, virtualbox

While installing Mountain Lion on VirtualBox, it starts booting, then stops at the line "root device uuid: xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx". I've allocated all the required RAM and memory, but even after looking online and fiddling with my settings I still can't get it to work. Any thoughts on how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this problem recently while attempting to install a Mountain Lion VM on my Mac Pro (10.10) using VirtualBox 4.3.2.  I was trying to follow the instructions [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/132789/how-to-install-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion-on-virtualbox-4-3), but I got stuck in the EFI boot sequence.  I attached a screenshot, but I think its where you got stuck too.

[image: Screen Shot of error]

I tried the same process on my macbook pro laptop (with the same iso), and it worked fine.

I fiddled with it for a while and found a solution.  If you follow those same [instructions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/132789/how-to-install-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion-on-virtualbox-4-3), but before you start the VM remove everything except CD/DVD from the boot order, it properly boots to the installer and you can continue with the process.

Forgive VM name typo
[image: ss]

Make sure you restore the boot order before it restarts.

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed it perfectly! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck enabled EFI and Clock hardware

Comment: Thank you! This was the only thing that actually got VirtualBox to run the .iso for me.